# How can a PC get turned into a vampire?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, undead

In the M.M. *(Monster Manual)*, it says that PC (*Player Characters*) can become vampires.

I'm not good at all with mythology, so I'm asking for a little help here.  How can a PC get turned into a vampire?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Much farther on in Vampire entry (p 297) in the stat block, there is an entry for the vampire's bite attack:

> **Bite (Bat or Vampire Form Only):** Melee Weapon Attack: +9 to hit, reach
>   5 ft., one willing creature, or a creature that is Grappled by the
>   vampire, Incapacitated, or Restrained. Hit: 7 (1d6 + 4) piercing
>   damage plus 10 (3d6) necrotic damage. The target's hit point maximum
>   is reduced by an amount equal to the necrotic damage taken, and the
>   vampire regains Hit Points equal to that amount. The reduction lasts
>   until the target finishes a Long Rest. *The target dies if this effect
>   reduces its hit point maximum to 0. A Humanoid slain in this way and
>   then buried in the ground rises the following night as a Vampire Spawn
>   under the vampire's control.*

The *italicized* emphasis is mine, and details the canonical, in-game mechanism for converting humanoids (including PCs) into vampire spawn.

The step from vampire spawn to vampire is detailed earlier, on page 295:

> If a true vampire allows a spawn to draw blood from its own body, the
>   spawn transforms into a true vampire no longer under its master's
>   control.  Few vampires are willing to relinquish the control in this manner.  Vampire spawn become free-willed when their creator dies.

[Interestingly, the rules-as-written imply that a vampire spawn whose creator vampire dies merely become free-willed vampire spawn, and do not get "promoted" to full vampire.]

[Equally interesting, a strict reading implies that True Vampire A can emancipate and promote the spawn of True Vampire B....]

Nothing precludes a GM from designing a setting with different or additional methods, of course.